# How to find common neighbours among nodes?

Tags: neo4j

I want to return a list of all members and count of their common neighbours with one specific node. So far I get the following:

```
MATCH (m:Member {name: 'Adam Smith'})-[]->(adamObjects)
MATCH (m2)-[]->(adamObjects)
WHERE m <> m2
RETURN m2.name, COUNT(adamObjects)
```

However, I am not sure if this is actually returning what I want. Any help is more than welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Provided that all :Member nodes are two relationships from each other, and that no other nodes of a different label are exactly two relationships from a :Member node, then your query is returning :Member nodes that are two relationships away from Adam, and the count of the nodes that are in common between them (at one relationship distant, outgoing from both members).